# Correct usage of primary key with timestamped data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a table which stores timestamped recordings from a collection of sensors, these readings are taken 14400 times per day. (every 6 seconds).

There are 4 sensors, and they share their main data table.

At the moment the schema is as follows:

```
id (int-PK)
time (DateTime)
sensor (int)
reading (int)
```

This works perfectly well, and I have the primary key set to autoincrement.

It seems silly to have this primary key at all however, since I *never* refer to it - Would I be better off using a combination of time and sensor to act as a composite key?

If I did use a composite key, I assume my bytes per row would be decreased too? This is relevant since the table is over 10m rows, so any saving is worth it.

It seems win-win, but I wanted to see what the repercussions of this approach would be.

Comment: What type of database is it? (e.g. is it Oracle, SQL Server.. ?)

Comment: MSSQL 2008 R2, although I don't see how my my question would be too technology specific?

Comment: I've never had anything but problems putting a datetime in a PK.  When your inserts start failing because of duplicates, you'll wish you hadn't done it.

Comment: In this case, inserts of duplicate data failing would be my expected behaviour.

Comment: Just checking whether your DB engine had any restrictions on datetimes and combined primary keys.

Comment: so you want to throw away data just because the "time" was the same?  I've seen many things recorded in log tables with the exact same time down to the fractional second, doesn't mean they occurred simultaneously, just that the precision of datetime isn't that granular.

Comment: what's a clustered index and why would one benefit you, composite or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time you are using a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). And you are evaluating to move to [natural keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key).

Working with surrogate keys has advantages over natural keys that you can learn about in previous link:

1. Immutability
2. Requirement changes
3. Performance
4. Compatibility
5. Uniformity

(From wikipedia)

You can look for some other posts about [surrogate v.s. natural keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) in stackoverflow.

But each design is different to others. As database analyst you should evaluate what is the best decission for your project.

Answer (score 2):

Composite indexes, and especially composite primary keys, should be avoided. The index is wider and this is bad for performance (and memory usage). In my personal opinion, it's also bad design to have a composite primary key, since there is no more unique singular way of referencing your row.

My advice would be to stick to the design you have now.

Comment: I have a clustered index based on the sensor and the timestamp (both ASC), are you saying this is a bad idea also?

Comment: Good point about the size of the index. I thought that since he was not using the PK in any way as a foriegn key reference say, then it would make no difference. But if space is the concern then this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

stick with the design, I've never had anything but problems putting a datetime in a PK. When your inserts start failing because of duplicates, you'll wish you hadn't done it.

if you want to save space go with a tiny int for the `sensor` column (you have only 4 different values). Possibly something smaller for `reading`, I doubt the sensor can record 2 trillion different values that an int can store, most likely you can use a smallint or tiny int for it.

```
bigint   8 bytes, -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
int      4 Bytes              -2,147,483,648 to             2,147,483,647
smallint 2 Bytes                     -32,768 to                    32,767
tinyint  1 byte                            0 to                       255
```

Comment: You raise a valid point, I could be getting away with a much smaller overhead for both my sensor and reading columns. As a quick question, would changing this on my database in retrospect cause me to lose data?

Comment: if all of your values will fit inside the new data types, then you will not have any problems.  You need to look into your clustered index and fill factor/padding to see if the column reductions will just go to more empty space per page.  If your not sure what I'm talking about, ask a new question (include the original table and clustered index create script from SSMS as well as the alter commands you intend on running)

Answer (score 0):

Using a combined primary key (or unique index) on 10M rows could easily eat up any storage space gained by removing the int PK (and more). Also, referencing a row from this table would become a lot more difficult.

I always keep an int (or bigint if required) PK on any table. The storage space is normally relatively small compared to the rest of the data and having an easy way of linking/referencing rows always in place makes life a lot easier WRT to enhancements and changes to your data model.